Suitable statistical test
I have 2 groups - people that were ever active on my website and people who were never active. Activity is a metric based on some actions - both groups of people visited the website.
Each group used a set of features during their first week on the website (it is sort of platform and the people are users), I would like to know, which features are correlated to "becoming active".
For example:
20 of the 100 active people used feature A 100 times within that group out of 3000 total feature usages.
3 of the 50 never active people used feature A 20 time within that group out of 1500 total feature usages.



Ever active
Feature
Accounts used
Total accounts
Feature used
Total feature usage




1
A
20
100
100
3000


0
A
3
50
20
1500



I can also add the variance and stdev of the feature usage.
What test could I do here to say that people who used feature A are in significantly higher correlation to become active?
Also, does it make sense to run any test on the accounts' proportions' themselves and use that test to claim that feature A is significantly more correlated to becoming active?
Thank you

There are a couple of possibilities. I’ll discuss two of them. First, if you simply want to examine whether feature A users tend to be “active”, you can do the following:
Assuming that it is possible to be not active, but use the feature you can simply cross-classify by status and usage:

Ever active = yes, feature A = yes
Ever active = no, feature A = yes
Ever active = yes, feature A = no
Ever active = no, feature A = no

And perform a $\chi^{2}$ test of independence, and then compute an odds ratio for being active given that you've used feature A.
Or, you could could do a test of proportions on the difference between the proportion of active accounts using feature A and the proportion of non-active accounts using feature A. By your table:
$$
\hat p_{1} = p(active, A) = \frac{20}{100} = 0.20 \\
\hat p_{2} = p(inactive, A) = \frac{3}{50} = 0.06 \\
\hat{p} = p(A) = \frac{20 + 3}{100 + 50} = \frac{23}{150} \approx 0.153
$$
Using the Z test:
$$
Z = \frac{(\hat p_{1} - \hat p_{2}) - 0}{\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})(\frac{1}{n_{1}} + \frac{1}{n_{2}} )  }} \\
= \frac{0.20 - 0.06}{\sqrt{0.153 \times (1 - 0.153) \times (0.01 + 0.02)}} \\
= \frac{0.14}{\sqrt{0.153 \times 0.847 \times 0.03 }} \\
\approx 9.53
$$
You could either use a critical value based on the standard normal distribution, or compute the tail probability of $z = 9.53$ (two tailed if you wish). Either way, the p-value is quite small (both one and two tails have $p <.00001$
If, however, you are more interested in distinguishing between two groups of people based on their feature usage, and you define usage as either binary (used v. Not used) or ordinal categorical for each feature, you could use Latent Class Analysis or a form of clustering to discern the pattern. Latent Class Analysis would enable you to estimate patterns of usage across as many latent groups as you wish.

You could use and not be active, yes. Regarding the second approach, are you sure it is correct to do a z or a t test considering the sample size and the proportion (therefore the numerator and denominator) are dependent? Also, what would be the best way to test for usage rate? Just t test for average usage within each group (and adding 0 to users who didn't use) ?

T test or use a Poisson model. T-test will give you difference in mean usage across groups, while Poisson gives you a test of rate per unit time

Perfect thanks. Should I add 0s to the users who haven't used the features? Because currently the averages do not reflect 0 usage users but rather just averages the usage done by the ones who used it

It depends. I would think a lot about what @jginestet wrote as these are really design questions. One way to approach is to ask what you would want to do if you could somehow randomize people to be users and non users. How would you want to compare them in that situation. Or the converse: randomize people to use feature A v not using it.

Having a controlled environment would be great and simpler. But I have a given situation from which I should try to infer what I can. So I took the usage only during the initial period of interaction with the feature. On a side note - the users are using the system for other sub products that don't have anything to do with the features I'm measuring. The idea is to see which features might deter people from continuing using the sub product and never become active, and which features might make them want to continue using it and become active (active is not defined by a single use).

Yes of course. It’s just a thought experiment. See, however, the end of my edited response.

I see your edit. I'm not sure why it is better than chi square for proportion. I'm guessing that would be the way to go.

It's not better. It's an option if you want to consider all features together. It's a multivariate technique. But I think between chi-square and the test of proportions, you're good to go

I am afraid that you may not be able to ever reach the conclusion you wanted to draw ("people who used feature A are in significantly higher correlation to become active?").
The fact is that people who are active (for some reason) are more likely to spend more time on your site, and thus to use any and all features more often. And non-active people are more likely to be "accidental tourists", and thus to spend little time, and use few features. What you find for feature A, you will probably also find for all features. In fact, the more obscure, burried features may be the ones which are the most significantly associated with being an active users (because only these would ever use them...).
Now, if you could look at the behavior of users who became active, but only up to the time they became active (whatever that trigger is), that may be more tenable (but you question does not indicate that this is what you are doing?). The actions of a user who became active, but before they became active, can be better compared to non-active users. Then a correlation of using feature X to becoming active would be more telling.
A final note. You could run a $\chi^2$ test, or a z-test, on the accounts, as @Rick Hass did in a previous answer (note that they both will give you exactly the same p-value, as, with 1 d.f., the $chi^2$ statistic is just a $Z^2$ statistic). But you could do the same (Z, $\chi^2$) on the number of times a feature was used; in your example data, they are both significant, but that may not always be the case?

Thank you for your input. You are right that there is a correlation between feature usage and becoming active however this is more of a platform we are talking about, and the features usage I'm looking at are part of one product and only during the first X day of trying out the product. I accept your general comment, and I didn't give this info, but I didn't want to explain the whole thought behind it and really just wanted to get the correct tests I can do on my data. BTW just to be sure, do I need to add 0 for users who didn't use certain features?
